# When is a new server instance better than just upgrading current one?

Tags: performance, server, scalability

I'm just wondering, usually huge web apps have a few server instances. When is a new server instance better than just upgrading the current one's memory, cpu and etc.?

I understand location reasons, but wondering about any other reasons.

Comment: Adding a new server you also increase your fault tolerance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few reasons off the top of my head why scaling horizontally can be better than scaling vertically:

1. Fault tolerance. A server can do down (or be taken down by you for
   maintenance/updates) and the site can stay online.
2. Red/black deployments. Let's say you have a new version of your software you want to roll out, but you're not 100% confident in how it works. If you have two or more servers, you can update one (and segment a % of your users to only use that server) and see how it goes. This way if there are egregious problems, you can roll back and only a few users will have seen problems.
3. You can treat your hardware as cattle and not pets. If you try to scale up one server to as large as it will go, you will need to be very careful with it. It will become a delicate flower that you don't allow anyone to touch. However if you have a bunch of cheaper, commoditized servers you can lose a few, update some, replace them at will. This will save you time and money in the long run.
4. Lastly, at *some* point you will not be able to scale up your one precious snowflake server. At that point what do you do? You now have to scale out while also dealing with a massive amount of traffic this one machine is handling. Better to do it earlier when things are simpler!